# How to call Objective-C libraries in dynamic framework Swift?

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift2

I have created a dynamic framework with Swift language. In this framework I am  using mailcore2-ios that was build by Objective-C code. So how can I use it in swift file of my framework?

I try "public" and add a header .h file to umbrella but it still not work, have so much error for other header file as the image what I attach.

[image: Attach File]

Comment: Also post errors as code not image.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not allow the use of bridging headers in framework targets. You should use the methods described here : http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2014/10/03/using-commoncrypto-in-swift/